# Android custom tts voice

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have done a lot of research around the topic. What I want is simply a custom voice (not default voice on device) for my app. Wherever I have searched people suggest using device default.

Best example is Jarvis app on Play store.

I would like to create a uniform experience on any device with this approach. Can someone suggest any good libraries or a way to achieve this?

Comment: http://www.ispeech.org/ ?

Comment: Thanks, looks good.:) Let me play around and get back.

Comment: Hi I have the same kind of requirement where in you record a sample voice and read any text withe the custom voice. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is tacotron from google for this purpose.
But i am not sure if the android version is available yet.
Its under developement and probably google assistent is using it.
But they use mostly cloud version on python.